# How to print shell_exec() error messages on the browser?

Tags: php, debian

I need to troubleshoot a sample of code but can't seem to find any error.

```
$date = $_POST['date'];
$strcommand = "python3 python.py ".$date.""; //date argument is passed to python 
echo $strcommand;
$command = shell_exec($strcommand);
echo $command; //proceeds a lot of calculations and then sends an automatic mail with python
```

When using this sample of code, **the python WILL run but the mail won't be send**. I can tell it runs because python returns `print()` statements, which are displayed in the browser. **However when an error occurs, I don't receive any error message from the system !**

Here is how I tried to identify the error : I copied the $strcommand from the browser and entered it in command line *(only replacing `$date` by the corresponding string)*, in the exact same directory where the php file is, and guess what, the python ran as expected and the mail was sent.

**How do I identify this error ?**

Comment: On line 2 the `"` are mismatched

Comment: This has been edited in the post. The real thing didn't have this syntax error. Thanks !

Comment: So now you are concatenating an empty string?  In addition, you have a file named `python.py` and you give us no indication what is in it.

Comment: The empty string works fine do not worry about that. The python string is not that interesting to solve the problem, considering it runs correctly when used from command line.

Basically it analyzes a set of data using python scientific libraries. The set of data depends on the given date and is retrieved from a database. Then it sends an automatic mail as a recap.

Comment: I've seen people concatenate empty strings many times, I've never been able to get them to explain why they do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error messages are printed to standard error instead of standard output, you need to redirect it so you can capture it in PHP.

```
$date = escapeshellarg($_POST['date']);
$strcommand = "python3 python.py $date 2>&1";
```